# Spotify client cannot play track when it's a premium ad

Tags: advertisements, spotify, music-streaming

When the Spotify desktop client goes to play a Spotify Premium ad it returns this error:

> Can't Play Current Track

It just started doing this earlier (possibly yesterday) and I don't know why. How can I fix it? Clearing my cache didn't help.

Comment: To the close voter: The faq says, and i quote, "If you have a question about ... computer software ... then you’re in the right place to ask your question!". I know that the faq says not to ask about web services, but my question is specifically about an error i'm having with the *client software*.

Comment: IDK about you but I'm not complaining… ;)

Just hit next and you're good to go.

Comment: Well, it's a little annoying when i'm in a game or something and I constantly have to keep restarting the music >.>

Comment: I'm surprised they don't have targeted ads—my music tastes do not include anything from the ads. And the in-house guys have annoying voices. But that's just me....

Comment: btw, @RCIX the fix should be coming soon https://twitter.com/#!/Spotify/status/106115135696936960

Answer (score 2):

Here is thread on the problem:

http://getsatisfaction.com/spotify/topics/spotify_cant_play_the_current_track_why?utm_medium=widget&utm_source=widget_spotify

I have had it happen on both my Mac and PC. It is probably a problem at Spotify and not the local software.